# Байты некорректно передаются в base64 из C# в Java

Tags: java, c#

Есть вот такой вот кусок кода на c# который конвертит интовский массив в base64.

```
int[] mas = new int[4] { 127, 15, 25, 118 };

byte[] binData = new byte[2 + 2 + 4 + 4];

BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)mas[0]).CopyTo(binData, 0);
BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)mas[1]).CopyTo(binData, 2);
BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)mas[2]).CopyTo(binData, 4);
BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)mas[3]).CopyTo(binData, 8);

string BASE64 = Convert.ToBase64String(binData);

Console.WriteLine(BASE64);
```

После этого я копирую получившуюся base64 последовательность и в java разбираю её по байтам с помощью ByteBuffer'а. Вот код.

```
byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode("fwAPABkAAAB2AAAA");
ByteBuffer tel=ByteBuffer.wrap(decoded);
int agg_id   =   tel.getInt(4);
int status   =  tel.get(8);
```

`getInt` по сути должен брать по 4 байта и и собирать эти 4 байта назад в число интовского типа. В байтах получается вот такая вот последовательность:

> 127 0 15 0 25 0 0 0 118 0 0 0

То есть getInt(4) должен взять 25 0 0 0. И сделать из них назад число 25 типа int. Но почему то в переменную agg_id записывается вот такое вот значение 419430400. Дебажил полностью проваливаясь в getInt и всё смотрел полностью но так и не понял почему такой результат. Может кто то подсказать в чём дело?

Comment: `tel.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);` может поможет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как уже написал @AndreyM в комментариях при передаче изменился [порядок байтов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) в представлении числа.

> ... getInt(4) должен взять 25 0 0 0. И сделать из них назад число 25 типа int. Но почему то в переменную agg_id записывается вот такое вот значение 419430400

25*256*256*256 = 419430400, т.е. `ByteBuffer` считает первый байт старшим.

В [документации `ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#wrap-byte:A-) действительно указано, что по-умолчанию принят [порядок от старшего к младшему](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D1.80.D1.8F.D0.B4.D0.BE.D0.BA_.D0.BE.D1.82_.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B0.D1.80.D1.88.D0.B5.D0.B3.D0.BE_.D0.BA_.D0.BC.D0.BB.D0.B0.D0.B4.D1.88.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.83):

> ... The initial order of a byte buffer is always BIG_ENDIAN.

Изменить порядок можно с помощью метода [`ByteBuffer.order`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order-java.nio.ByteOrder-):

```
ByteBuffer tel=ByteBuffer.wrap(decoded);
tel.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
int agg_id   =   tel.getInt(4);
...
```

Для сведения, порядок байтов, который использует [`BitConverter.GetBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1184xdy4(v=vs.110).aspx) определяется свойствами машины:

> The order of bytes in the array returned by the GetBytes method depends on whether the computer architecture is little-endian or big-endian.

Порядок в текущей системе можно проверить с помощью [`BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Спасибо большое, и как будет в таком случае происходить вычисление? Если я изменю порядок? на что перемножится 25?

Comment: Или просто последний нолик будет перемножаться на 256 3 раза? и в результате само собой нечего не измениться.

Comment: @Андрей получится 25 ([0*256^3+0*256^2+0*256+25*1](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое.